# Add html within textNode in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var node = document.createTextNode('Hello World');
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(node);
```

I also want a `<br />` between each Hello World

`createTextNode` is not allowing any html.

Any work around?

Comment: `<br>` is an element, you'd use `createElement` to create elements, and elements can't exist inside textNodes, that's why they are called textnodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var node = document.createElement('div');
node.innerHTML = 'Hello World<br>';
document.documentElement.appendChild(node);
```

You can copy this code to your console and see the result immediately

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I was dreading how complicated this was going to get  ^_^